# Finding Duplicate String Arrays

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, list, sorting

I have a large list of string arrays, and within this `List<string[]>` there can be arrays with all same values (and possibly with different indexes). I'm looking to find and count these **duplicate** string arrays and have a `Dictionary<string[], int>` with `int` being the count (however if there is a better way than using a dictionary I would be interested in hearing). Does anyone have any advice on how to achieve this? Any and all input is very appreciated, thanks!

Comment: can u give examples on what you are trying to achieve ?

Comment: What is the int key supposed to store?  That cant be the count since you could have many arrays with the same count

Comment: Please elaborate your question with sample data. `Dictionary<int, string[]>` is quite confusing

Comment: @bryanmac ahh yes was just thinking of `int` to be the count but `Dictionary<string[], int>` would make more sense. thanks for pointing that out

Comment: @Saleem Thanks I revised the question slightly and will try to have a sample up soon

Comment: So What are you expecting? number of times a string appears in list?

Comment: @Saleem Expecting number of specific repeating string array. There are many arrays with same string values (but may be not be in same order with same indexes)

Comment: So what should be consider duplicate? string array with same order or even without order?

Comment: @Saleem either is considered a duplicate, sorry for not elaborating this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use linq `GroupBy` with a `IEqualityComparer` to compare the `string[]`

```
var items = new List<string[]>() 
    { 
        new []{"1", "2", "3" ,"4" }, 
        new []{"4","3", "2", "1"},
        new []{"1", "2"}
    };

var results = items
        .GroupBy(i => i, new UnorderedEnumerableComparer<string>())
        .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Count());
```

The `IEqualityComparer` for the unordered list

```
public class UnorderedEnumerableComparer<T> : IEqualityComparer<IEnumerable<T>>
{
    public bool Equals(IEnumerable<T> x, IEnumerable<T> y)
    {
        return x.OrderBy(i => i).SequenceEqual(y.OrderBy(i => i));
    }
    // Just the count of the array, 
    // it violates the rule of hash code but should be fine here
    public int GetHashCode(IEnumerable<T> obj)
    {
        return obj.Count();
    }
}
```

[.Net Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/p23ehI)

Answer (score 0):

You might find duplicate keys if you use number of occurrences as a `Key` to  `Dictionary` I would suggest use `Dictionary<string, int>` where key represents the string and value represents no of occurrences. Now we can use `Linq` statements.

```
var results = items.SelectMany(item=>item)
                   .GroupBy(item=>item)
                   .ToDictionary(g=>g.Key, g=>g.Count());
```

Other approach is having [`LookUp`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb460184(v=vs.100).aspx), which allows a collection of keys each mapped to one or more values

```
var lookup = items.SelectMany(item=>item)
                  .GroupBy(item=>item)
                  .ToLookup(c=>c.Count(), c=>c.Key);
```

Working [`example`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/B0iaWm)

Comment: Hmm I think this is just counting and grouping single strings from all arrays in list? It doesn't need to compare strings, but each array of strings and group by / count array with all same string values

Comment: in that case second approach (lookup) should work to you.

Comment: Ahh... now I got what you mean,  you want grouping at per array and count duplicates with in that array, is that correct?

Comment: No i think your second approach is what I'm looking for, just running into an issue with SelectMany. I think because i actually have `string[]`'s inside of an `object`. 

`Error CS0411: The type arguments for method System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectMany<TSource,TResult>(this System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>, System.Func<TSource,System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TResult>>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly`

Comment: Oh I got the same results with second approach. Nope there aren't any duplicates within each array - pretty much am looking to group and count in a scenario like:

`new [] { "camera", "lens", "tripod" } == new [] { "camera", "tripod", "lens" }`

Comment: That means you need `Array` comparison and grouping based on arrays?

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Q1 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("String entry here --> ");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String entry = input.nextLine();
    String[] words = entry.split("\\s");         
    System.out.println(words.length);
    for(int i=0; i<words.length; i++){
        int count = 0;
        if(words[i] != null){
            for(int j=i+1;j<words.length;j++){
                if(words[j] != null){
                    if(words[i].equals(words[j])){
                        words[j] = null;
                        count++;
                    }
                }
                else{
                    continue;
                }
            }
            if(count != 0){
                System.out.println("Count of duplicate " + words[i] + " = " + count );

            }
        }
        else{
            continue;
        }
    }
    input.close();
}
}
```